# pushing up with negative margin and stay visible

Tags: css

I have 2 divs in an outer div. The outer div has a top margin so there is a space above it. I want to move the left inner div a little up to fill some of that space. I did a minus margin-top.. it works, it pushes the left inner div up.. but it hides the top 10px that moved up. I want them to stay visible.

I tried making the div have z-index to the front (1) but it does not work. I want to move the inner left div up and want the pushed up part to stay visible.

```
<div id="line"> //style margin-top:30px

  <div id="lineleft"> //style margin-top:-10 z-index=1
  </div>

  <div id="lineright">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have `overflow: hidden` applied to the outer `div`?

Comment: @Yi Jiang, wow that was really good of you. I had `overflow: auto` and removed it and solved the problem. Please post as answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to change the value of the `overflow` property on the outer div.

Comment: Just discovered that I need that overflow auto. without it the background of outer div collapses. ah, what to do? any ideas?

Comment: @jblue It's for the `float` s, right? You'll need a clearfix (search for this term) element - an element below the outer div with `clear: both` applied. Alternatively, if you already have an element below it, apply `clear: both` to that

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working here in all major browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/rBTtt/